# hive query to check for entries added in a particular month that do not exist already in the database

Tags: hive

I need to check for new emailId's added in 06-2016 that have not existed in database ever before that.

I wrote the query using NOT IN operator:

```
select DISTINCT SF.customer_email
FROM 
Magento.sales_flat_order SF
WHERE
YEAR(TO_DATE(SF.created_at)) = '2016'
AND 
MONTH(TO_DATE(SF.created_at)) = '6'
AND 
SF.customer_email 
NOT IN (
select SFO.customer_email FROM Magento.Sales_flat_order SFO 
WHERE
TO_DATE(SFO.created_at) <= '2016-05-31'
)
```

I have verified that there are new emaiid's in the time but it returns empty result-set. Why is that? Infact, When I replace NOT IN operator with IN operator, it does return me the common ones but somehow NOT IN is behaving erratically.

Answer (score 0):

Use tradition sql approach left join

IE

`with result  as (select DISTINCT SF.customer_email
        FROM  Magento.sales_flat_order SF
        WHERE YEAR(TO_DATE(SF.created_at)) = '2016' AND MONTH(TO_DATE(SF.created_at)) = '6' )
        , result2  (select DISTINCT SFO.customer_email FROM Magento.Sales_flat_order SFO  WHERE TO_DATE(SFO.created_at) <= '2016-05-31')
        select  result.customer_email from result left join result2 on result.customer_email =result2.customer_email
        where result2.customer_emai is NULL OR result2.customer_emai='' OR length(result2.customer_emai) = 0`

**Note** :   result2.customer_emai is NULL would be sufficient in case of null column value is properly handled  .